GODOT 4 -- Link character body mesh with a skeleton (animations)
I've been on this problem for 2 weeks now and I unable to figure it out. I am working on the character for a FPS game. Here is my plan:

Slice the character mesh in 2 (head and rest of body) DONE
Add the skeleton with animations DONE
Bind the "head" sliced mesh with the skeleton DONE
PROBLEM > How do I bind the rest of the body (which is a single mesh) with the skeleton so the animations would work?

This is how I handled the head mesh binding with the skeleton. I have create a Physical Bone Head and then attached the head to the its collision - For a little while I thought that adding a skin would solve the problem - but I was wrong.
Please show me where I can get help on this problem because I may be in the position of not knowing how to Google my issue...
Thanks kind people,
Goofy.


Nothing to do with unity, get your tags right next time :P

If I understand correctly, the mesh never had an skeleton, correct? If that is the case what you are trying to do is to rig it, and Godot does not have that functionality. You need to give it the skeleton in another software (e.g. Blender). Then when you import it it will come with the skeleton, and you can add the head the way you did.
Then for the animation - which I presume was another file with the animated skeleton and no mesh - you can make it point to the skeleton imported with the mesh - assuming the skeleton are equal, there should be no trouble.

With that said, until Godot 4.3 I won't recommend this workflow. Instead, what I suggest is to have the mesh with skeleton and all the animations in a single file.
Yes, I'm aware that Unreal and Unity work with an FBX per animation, and yet another for the mesh, but - again before Godot 4.3 - that workflow is not viable in Godot (and likely it will be a viable but a pain in Godot 4.3). Instead Merge all the FBX in a single GLB or GLTF using a 3D editor such as Blender, and import that into Godot.
